# Change the class attribute value outside the class

Tags: python

I have a library like this:

```
class Robot:
    __counter = 0

    @classmethod
    def get_c(cls):
        result = cls.__counter + 1
        return result
```

I'm trying to access this class with initializing the class attribute __counter = 1, so I can get 2 from get_c() function.
This is what I did:

```
Robot.__counter = 1
x = Robot()
x.get_c()
```

why the result is still 1 and what is the solution of doing what I want without touching the class internally
thanks!

Comment: Why *oh why*, are you using double-underscore name-mangling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've used [double-underscore name-mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables). That translate every time you do:

```
__some_var
```

*Inside a class definition* into:

```
_MyClass__some_var
```

That's it's entire point - to avoid name-collisions in subclasses.

Just don't use double-underscore name-mangling if you want to access it outside the class like that.

I'm not sure what you mean precisely by "without touching the class internally", but in this case:

```
Robot._Robot__counter = 1
```

Would *work*, although doing the above is a sign you shouldn't be using double-underscore name-mangling.

As an aside, this is not equivalent to "private" in languages with access modifiers, although, it serves the same purpose for a *limited* use-case, preventing accidental name-collisions in subclasses.